# recognized selector giving me "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, gmail

I'm using Gdata to fetch contacts from a Gmail account. I'm able to fetch some details of the users (name etc') but when I try to fetch the email I'm getting this error:

```
-[GDataEntryBase emailAddresses]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

From what I've read i'm doing it in the right way. What am I missing?

Code:

```
      -(void)getGoogleContacts {

        GDataServiceGoogleContact *service =
        [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];

        NSString *username = @"username@gmail.com";
        NSString *password = @"pass";

        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];

        [service setUserAgent:@"McGraggerSoft-GoogleContactUtility-1.0"];
        [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username password:password];

        ticket = [service fetchContactFeedForUsername:username delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(ticket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
    }


- (void)ticket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedContact *)feed error:(NSError *)error
    {

        if ([[feed entries] count] > 0) {

            GDataEntryContact *firstContact = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0];
            GDataTextConstruct *titleTextConstruct = [firstContact title];
            NSString *title = [titleTextConstruct stringValue];    
            NSLog(@"first contact's title:%@", title);
           GDataEmail *email = [[firstContact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0]; //<-- Crash
          //NSString *ContactEmail = [email address];
          //NSLog(@"ContactEmail: %@",ContactEmail);
        }
    }
```

This is the project I'm using: https://github.com/819419423/GDataWithGTMOauth2Example
You can delete everything in the main controller and add the above methods to get the error.

Comment: Check if `GDataEntryContact` contains method named `emailAddresses `

Comment: there is emailAddresses  functionality not present  present in  firstContact class may be that is the reason.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya emailAddresses is inside GDataEntryContactBase.h. Sunny, I didn't understand your comment, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had an old version of GData. I've downloaded it from the download section instead of doing a **svn checkout**. After that everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically calling a method in an object that doesn't has it. In this case, the:

```
GDataEntryContact *firstContact = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Is assumed to have the method `emailAddresses`. So I guess the problem is occurring here:

```
GDataEmail *email = [[firstContact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0]; //<-- Crash
```

**How to fix it?**

Implement the method `emailAddresses` in your object.

Another thing that might be happening is that your emailAddresses is actually an ivar, and you only need to synthesize his getter/setter method, so just add this in your GDataEmail.h file:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *emailAddresses;
```

Comment: Adding the @property to GDataEmail.h didn't helped. Adding the method `emailAddresses`also didn't helped and the method in my project won't get called. I edited my question with the sample project i'm using. I've deleted everything inside it and added the above methods.

Comment: Well the `GDataEntryContact` doesn't have an emailAddress `@property` or a method called that. Since it's a static library you cannot change it, well you can change the .h, but wouldn't do anything for you actually.

Comment: So how do I fetch the contact Email address ? doing this: `            GDataEntryContactBase *firstContact = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0];
            GDataEmail *email = [[firstContact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];` Gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

While trying to get an instance of `GDataEntryContact` you seem to get an instance of `GDataEntryBase` as the error message tells. And this class does not provide the method `emailAddresses`. Please note that the Objective-C compiler doesn't prevent assignments of "type" id to - in this case - `firstContact`. So you might be thinking to have a `GDataEntryContact` object but in reality it's a `GDataEntryBase` object in `[[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0]`.